# CLLocationManager with kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation not very accurate

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I'm developing an app for runners, so I need high accuracy GPS coordinates. The Android version is ready, now I'm testing with the iOS version. I use the default location provider in Swift in this way:

```
locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
            locationManager.distanceFilter = 1.0
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
```

And I process coordinates in this way:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        let location = locations.last as CLLocation?
        let accuracy = location?.horizontalAccuracy

}
```

When accuracy is lower than 20, I process the coordinate in 'location' and show the location on a map. This is working fine, but the accuracy is far from good.

kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation should give the best results, but...

Today, I was testing with two devices at the same time: one Android device (price: $150) and a iPhone X (price: $1000). The Android device shows me the location all the time maximum 10 meters from my real location. The iPhone X, with code above, shows me in 70% of the time a location approximately 30-40 meters from my real location. It's not good enough for a running app which gives spoken instructions.

It can't be that the GPS receiver in an iPhone X is of a lower quality than a GPS receiver in a Huawei Y5? The environmental conditions were exactly the same.

Is there a way to receive more accurate locations?

Comment: In my experience the GPSs in Apple's iPhones is not great. With wide open view of the sky I'm lucky to get 20m accuracy, often 30-50 instead.

Comment: Yes it seems the problem it is the hardware... a real shame when you see how much these devices cost. Huawei Y5 is far more accurate. Unbelievable.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to you

```
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
```

knowing that this option will use the most power from your device as per the documentation in the below link

[CLLocationAccuracy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationaccuracy)

note that the below code is intended to be used for automobile navigation

```
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but this is wat docs say about kCLLocationAccuracyBest: "Specify this constant when you want very high accuracy but do not need the same level of accuracy required for navigation apps." (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/kcllocationaccuracybest). On many docs on the internet, I read that kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation should give the best location... Am I wrong?

Comment: you are more than welcome \n I suggested this answer as the requested info as per the question is as follows ---"I need high accuracy GPS coordinates"--- & ---"Is there a way to receive more accurate locations?"---

Comment: I just tested with kCLLocationAccuracyBest. Same problem. Android device, which is much cheaper, is more accurate. iOS location updates are most of time 30-40 meter from the real location. It must be the hardware: the GPS sensor of a expensive iPhone X is less accurate than the one in a 10 times cheaper device.